# Under which OS is Eclipse most robust?

Tags: java, android, xml, operating-system

Eclipse was developed using Java 6, so using the latest stable release of Java 6...

Under which OS eg. Windows 7, Funduntu, Ubuntu or MacOSX is Eclipse most robust?

Reason for question:

I, like many other people, consider Eclipse to be the best IDE to develop android applications. However, that doesn't mean that its very good. I think that the reason that it isn't very good is because it has been developed to be compatible with as many system setups as possible. Its an impossible task. In fact, finding a single setup that works flawlessly is proving very difficult, but I WILL find at least one.

Edit:

It appears that the different OS's have never been compared before, so I will test over the next few weeks and report my findings back here.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with running Eclipse in Windows 7. What makes you say it's designed with a different OS in mind?

Comment: _I have 16GB memory, 3.4Ghz i5, 1TB Solid state Hard drive machine_ this should be more more enough for a eclipse to run, in fact I run 5 instances on my 4GB ram simultaneously .. so it should not pose any problem.. and it works same in all **supported** platform.. so again this shouldn't be a problem

Comment: You would probably get more out of this if you state what problem(s) you are having that make you think you need to change OS. As with that system you really shouldn't be having any problems.

Comment: Hello Flup. It doesn't work like other Windows software, and will close unexpectedly which I can only guess is down to memory leaks. It doesn't even install like other software does, and to configure it you have to edit a config file when it should be using the registry. The interface must be using non-standard libraries, because it ignores Windows presets and responds differently to for example Visual Studio. It requests Administrator permission each time it runs.

Comment: It's not normal that it closes unexpectedly and asks for administrator permission when you run it.

Comment: I do not have OS tunnel vision. I do write software though, and it is natural to write software differently depending on the software's target environment. I just need to know which environment is Eclipse's target environment. At the moment it feels like I've installed a clio body kit to a mercedes.

Comment: Why did you say that? You have given me ideas for performing my own tests, but neither answer nor solution as of yet.

Comment: I can guess why the Administrator UAC dialog is being prompted.  Java apps run through JRE of course so your 'starting mindset' for launching eclipse should be that it only has user file permissions and it's starting from where your Java RunTime is installed and not eclipse itself.  If you did something like extract Eclipse to C:\ or really actually anywhere not a child of c:\user\ [username] \ then you'll get a UAC dialog every time from java being denied outside it's permitted file access.  Move eclipse within your user profile and it should stop doing that.

Comment: Thanks Chillax, I'll try that. I did in fact extract eclipse to S: before moving it to C:Program Files (or it may have been Program Files x86). I don't understand how that would make a difference, but then I can hardly claim to know everything about Windows. The more I delve, the more I uncover

Comment: Remember that Eclipse (and Java apps in general I believe?) doesn't care about your amount of available memory. They care about how much you let them use. Check out the eclipse.ini file and the -Xms and -Xmx arguments. There's also -XX:MaxPermSize which can cause Eclipse to hang (suicide through garbage collection) if it's set too low. Check the memory usage in your task manager. If it's close to any of these max limits, that's probably the cause of the instability.

Comment: In that form the question is not constructive. After some effort to rewrite it could be a good candidate for SuperUser. After removing all emotional context and doing some effort to localize the performance problems in OPs case it could actually be a good question.

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins make sure you mark one answer as accepted

Comment: for me, eclipse on mac has been faster than eclipse on Windows and crashes less. I will be soon trying it out on Ubuntu distro and update here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclipse has builds available and packages for all major OS, so choose your pick from here:

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Check the drop down list in the top right corner.

This is my first and only option(Eclipse) when developing Android. And it is free.

P.S. Then I would recommend with all my heart : Linux OS any version. It is fast and hasn't the problems of Win OS. Also is faster and it's performance is better.

I found this interesting article now: http://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/708977-the-2013-top-7-best-linux-distributions-for-you

> Best Desktop Distribution
>
> There are so many excellent contenders for desktop Linux this year
>   that it's become a more difficult choice than ever – and that's really
>   saying something.
>
> Canonical's Ubuntu has made great strides in advancing Linux's
>   visibility in the public eye, of course, while Linux Mint and Fedora
>   are both also very strong choices. Regarding Ubuntu, however, a number
>   of issues have come up over the past year or so, including the
>   inclusion of online shopping results in searches – an addition Richard
>   Stallman and the EFF have called “spyware.”
>
> Fuduntu logo
>
> At the same time, the upheaval caused by the introduction of
>   mobile-inspired desktops such as Unity and GNOME 3 continues unabated,
>   spurring the launch of more classically minded new desktops such as
>   MATE and Cinnamon along with brand-new distros.
>
> For best desktop Linux distro, I have to go with Fuduntu, one of this
>   new breed of up-and-comers. Originally based on Fedora but later
>   forked, Fuduntu offers a classic GNOME 2 interface – developed for the
>   desktop, not for mobile devices -- and generally seems to get
>   everything right.
>
> Besides delivering the classic desktop so many Linux users have made
>   clear that they prefer, Fuduntu enjoys all the advantages of being a
>   rolling release distribution, and its repository includes key packages
>   such as Netflix and Steam. I've been using it for months now and

Comment: I know that many environments are supported, but which is the best. My gut feeling is a Linux based system, but I really don't know. I will only know if I vigorously test it, but before I do that I wondered if someone else had already done one.

Comment: This is sounding very promising. The readme in eclipse also says "In general, the 4.2 release of the Eclipse Project is developed on Java SE 6 VM" so I will install that too. I think even version numbers mean a stable release if I remember correctly. Thank you Floradu88

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to switch to Linux for the sake of running Eclipse.

Comment: Yes, but from my experience JAVA ENV works best on Linux

Comment: I'd call this a matter of taste rather than making an actual difference.

Comment: Flup. You are deviating from the question with false facts. Your favourite operating system is Windows and that's your choice. However, I am not trying to choose a favourite operating system, and judging by your comments, what you would call something and what something actually is are two different things. Floradu has been the most helpful so far, so please; either contribute or go away. I'm flagging your comments as unconstructive/off topic

Comment: Okay, this is becoming unconstructive. I have no favorite because it makes no difference. I use both.

Comment: I still think its worth testing, but thanks for the input Flup.

Answer (score 3):

I would have used direct comment replies but my stack ranking isn't quite there yet.

You cited above the reasons for not liking eclipse as it not using the registry and not looking like Windows operating system UI elements.  That's more than just eclipse, that's generally how most things in Java go.  It's not impossible for a Java application to use the windows styling for it's user interface but that's extra work I'd say the majority of Java apps will not have had put into them.   Realistically there's no reason this should scare you away though and you will run into the same things you've cited when doing Android development in other Java based IDEs.  IntelliJ for example does much of the same.

Comment: Ahh I see! It hadn't occured to me that Eclipse was itself written in java. In which case it might be worth finding out which version of java is best to run Eclipse under too

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins any version of java works with Eclipse

Comment: You should be able to run it easily under the current stable version of Java x64 for Windows.   I'm currently using Eclipse Juno in such a setup, Java 7 x64bit on Windows 8 x64.  My hardware's also not nearly as beefy as yours but it works quite alright for me.  You just need to adjust mindset for the odd user interface looks and if that truly bothers you Eclipse and IntelliJ both can be skinned and colored at will.

Comment: I'll also add that one annoyance you're going to run into with Java (not an eclipse thing, but java itself) is that the 64bit distributions for some reason that's totally lost on me fail to add a PATH environment variable to windows for the java executable.  This causes windows to go "Java? WTF is java?" even after installing Java Run Time.  It's a quirk in any x64 version of windows + 64bit java.   The 32bit JRE won't have this issue but you prob want the 64bit one if you've got that power house machine.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I'm happy to learn new stuff and not have the interface animating gleeful colours around the screen for enhanced programming excitement; I just want an ideal setup to develop android. At the moment, I'm putting up with Eclipse's unique character for now, because I haven't found a more productive alternative yet. Its a great piece of software, but to be blunt, C# development in Visual Studio is a breath of fresh air after three months of Eclipse (I have to open Visual Studio now and again you see), and Visual Studio is far from perfect itself

Comment: Ditto, I suppose.  I type a lot but it's not to insinuate anything.  I've just run into the oddities you've mentioned, they aren't that Eclipse works worse on Windows, it's just not always as intuitive as you might expect it to be.

Comment: No problemo Chillax. I'm just trying to find the best work around. I wish there was a non-java android editor for Windows with the functionality of Eclipse, but with the robustness of Visual Studio, but  at best, its a wish to the wind - someone might catch it, but it doesn't help in the short term.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is as generic as it gets, but really: it's completely up to you. Java is supposed to be completely platform-independent and your with a computer as strong as yours, I doubt there are many things you will not be able to do. For the sake of ease of use, I'd simply use the OS that like most, regardless of the fact that you're using it for eclipse right now.

Comment: There's too much change going on to justify chaining myself to a paticular OS, especially since I'm developing for android it would make most sense to attach a keyboard to I dunno a Nexus 10 or something, and  develop on that. Is there even a build of Eclipse for android though? Most importantly, the question above rings out, 'is it the best way to develop android software?'

Comment: Well... funny you should say that.  There IS such an alternative that can [develop for android on android](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui).  That said I've never personally used it but it does exist.

Comment: Do you know the name of the app? Is it Aide?

Comment: There's a link in my text above there to it in the Play Store.  That is the name however yes.

Comment: So there is. Sorry, I failed to notice the link. I'll check it out. I've been looking for an excuse to get a bolt on keyboard for the Nexus 10. This could be it

Answer (score 2):

You didn't describe what bothers you, is it Eclipse itself? Uploading to the Emulator? Debugging on the Emulator?

There are many ways to improve Eclipse/Android performance.
The easiest one is to install Linux
:)

I have a dual-boot machine with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10.
It takes longer to some tasks to complete on Windows (but I didn't use a watch so I might be wrong).
Examples are starting an emulator and uploading an application to the emulator.

Installing Ubuntu side by side Windows is very simple so you can try it out easily, please let us know the results.

Also:
Start Eclipse with a fixed heap size suitable to your machine:

```
eclipse -data "your-workspace" -vmargs -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
```

Last:
At least some believe that you should always start the emulator from the AVD Manager and not by the debugger.

Hope this helps
/Yaron

Comment: I had a hunch it may be Linux, but I don't want to go on gut instinct. Its looking increasingly like noone has tested Eclipse further than their own machine except for you. 'll certainly give Linux a try next. Would you recommend Ubuntu? I have downloaded install dics for Ubuntu in the past

Comment: I haven't needed to use the emulator in a long time thankfully. My test bed is a Samsung Nexus 10 or an Asus Nexus 7. Its my job. I dread the day I have to use the emulator. I found that the most significant issue with the emulator boils down to screen size. A smaller screen loads much quicker and faster than a smaller one. Even if dropping the size by small bits. I cant run Nexus 10 sized displays

Comment: Thanks Yaron, all contributions are very helpful and gratefully received

Answer (score 2):

It should run fast on every OS. I read recently eclipse is slower on linux if You use other jdk than sun.
There are few trick to faster your IDE:

- Disable unecessary validations in reference
- Disable unwanted plugins
- Configuring eclipse.ini should be [based on your RAM](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) -
  increase `XX:PermSize` and `Xms` to match your RAM

I think it is a great trick:
create a ram disk(virtual disk) on memory, and put your jdk on the this ram disk. Use for example imdisk.

Comment: Does this include the latest Oracle ones, or do they count as Sun?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse works great for Android development, both on Windows and on Linux. This is due to the way it's built, it uses Java and does not rely on any operating system specifics.

The problems you cite are not specific to the OS but to your installation.

Comment: Can you develop this into an answer please Flup. You sound like you are suggesting that there is little to no different between running different software under different versions of Java, running in different OSs on different machines. If you can prove this then I'll save my time and not bother testing

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best option is to use [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) its free for Android Development.

Edit: Available on Win, Mac, Linux.

Comment: This is a subjective opinion, in-fact most android developers feel Eclipse has a good environment for Android development than other IDEs.

Comment: @PradeepSimha Yes, but all around me who have used Eclipse and tried to Idea - never goes back.

Comment: I'll give it a go after (or maybe alongside) Fuduntu + Eclipse. Do you know which OS is the target for IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins, Idea available on Win, Mac, Linux. I don't know target OS, but i worked in Idea on Windows and on Mac. And I can say that there is no difference, all work like a charm. Except italic style of letter "w" on Windows ;)

Comment: I'm using Ultimate (paid edition), so not sure if what I say goes for the free one as well, however: I find it kinda funny that Android development is so much better integrated in IDEA than in Eclipse without official support.

Answer (score 0):

```
 which environment is best for Android development?
```

> Operating Systems Windows XP (32-bit), Vista (32- or 64-bit), or
>   Windows 7 (32- or 64-bit) Mac OS X 10.5.8 or later (x86 only) Linux
>   (tested on Ubuntu Linux, Lucid Lynx) GNU C Library (glibc) 2.7 or
>   later is required. On Ubuntu Linux, version 8.04 or later is required.
>   64-bit distributions must be capable of running 32-bit applications.

This is the pic of copied data from [android.developer.com](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider these avenues later on